# Is there a way to detect and remove the G-Clef without using database in Opencv in c++?

Tags: opencv

Detecting and removing all the G clef, please help me I need the knowledge for this, and I am still a student, who also seek your advice that you can provide for me so that I can learn more interesting stuff. Thank you for your respond and i hope that you can provide me with the source code :) Thank you very much

[image] [H]

Comment: cv::matchTemplate should work there.

Comment: thank you for the valuable advise, i will try it.

Comment: may i ask how does matchTemplate works?

Comment: like block matching. see openCV documentation for details: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html

Comment: can i loop the matchtemplate to detect all g clef and F clef?

Comment: with a single call you can find all occurances of one template. instead of minmaxloc you have to find all positions with low/high values

Comment: is there a way to remove what i found? like something if the g clef is found then i will like remove the whole row of the g clef

Comment: overwrite the region witj white color